# Send email based on cell value

Tags: javascript, loops, email, google-apps-script, columnsorting

I am trying to have this script loop per column. If a date in the column is the same as today's date, the script will send an email using the persons name and email address detailed in the same row.

[Table of Expiry Dates](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lJDrx.png)

```
function myFunction() 
{
  var spreadSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var dataRange = spreadSheet.getDataRange();

  var data = dataRange.getValues();
  var date = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT", "dd/MM/yyyy")
  
  
  var engcheck1 = dataRange.getColumn[2];
  
  for (var i = 1; i < data.length; i++)
  if (engcheck1 == date)
  {
      var row = data[i];
      var emailAddress = row[7]; //position of email header — 1
      var name = row[1]; // position of name header — 1
      var subject = "Your Currency for Engineering is now expired";
      var text = "Please note that your currency has expired today (" + date +"). You are now unauthorised to carry out any engineering tasks until you have been signed off by a member of the engineering team.";
      var message = "Dear " + name + "," + "\n\n" + text + "\n\n" + "Please get back in currency at your earliest convenience." + "\n\n" + "Many thanks," + "\n" + "Dominic Paul"
      MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
  }(i);
}
```

Without the 'If' statement, the script will loop through each row and sending out an email address. When I include the 'If' statement, nothing is sent to the email addresses. Either I am using the if statement incorrectly or I am not targeting the column accurately. I tried creating a variable engcheck1 for column 2 ONLY but no email is sent despite today being one of the dates in column 2 (C).

Comment: Please [don’t post images of code, error messages, or other textual data.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors) Please [edit] to replace the image with text and add tags to identify which programming language you are using. Is this Javascript?

Comment: Hiya @tripleee. I only have a snippet image of the table I am using with the code. I have pasted the code in format text based on the given format:  
```
like so
```
I have added the tags. This is indeed Java.

Comment: So what is the question? What is the expected and actual results?

Comment: Do you mean Java, like you say in your comment, or Javascript? The two are completely unrelated, and the naming clash is frustrating. (Java was "cool" and "trending" at the time, so the marketers at Netscape wanted to hitch a ride on that.)

Comment: @NikitaSkrebets I have added a more context above.

Comment: @tripleee that would be Javascript as per the google apps script standard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not understand, what is `var engcheck1 = dataRange.getColumn[2];`.
If you need to send and email if `date` is the same as the value in `C` column, provided column `C` has type `Plain text`, this is the answer:

```
function myFunction() {
  var spreadSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var dataRange = spreadSheet.getDataRange();

  var lastRow = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getDataRange().getNumRows();
  var dateData = spreadSheet.getRange("C1:C" + lastRow).getDisplayValues().flat();
  var data = dataRange.getValues();
  
  var date = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT", "dd/MM/yyyy")

  for (var i = 1; i < data.length; i++) {
    var rowDate = dateData[i];
    var row = data[i];
    // if the date in row is the same as date variable
    if (rowDate === date) {
      var emailAddress = row[7]; //position of email header — 1
      var name = row[1]; // position of name header — 1
      var subject = "Your Currency for Engineering is now expired";
      var text = "Please ...";
      var message = "Dear ...";
      MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
    };
  }
}
```

Comment: Thankyou, this has helped. It works when I have a random clear text such as: (rowDate === 'dominic') with dominic inserted inside one of the cells, however, when I insert an actual date in the same format as "dd/MM/yyyy", nothing happens which I believe the script is having a problem with comparing the dated format from the excel sheet itself.

Comment: @DominicPaul, I made adjustments so now it should perceive date as string always. Please check it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function myFunction() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var rg = sh.getDataRange();
  var vs = rg.getValues();
  const dt = new Date();
  var dtv = new Date(dt.getFullYear(),dt.getMonth(),dt.getDate()).valueOf();
  vs.forEach((r,i) => {
    let d = new Date(r[2]);
    let dv = new Date(d.getFullYear(),d.getMonth(),d.getDate()).valueOf();
    if(dv == dtv ) {
      //send you email
    }
  })
}
```